# Get file from JAR to use in build.sbt dependencyCheck

Tags: jar, dependencies, sbt, configuration-files, owasp

We have a jar that has a file in its root named "dependency-check-suppressions.xml". This jar is used to make sure we always have the latest suppressions whenever there is a build.

In maven, we simply reference this jar and set this filename in the dependency-check plugin, it finds it and works great, like so:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.owasp</groupId>
    <artifactId>dependency-check-maven</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <suppressionFiles>
            <suppressionFile>dependency-check-suppressions.xml</suppressionFile>
        </suppressionFiles>
    </configuration>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.example</groupId>
            <artifactId>owasp-suppressions</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

I would like to do the same thing in sbt, by referencing the JAR in libraryDependencies and then mentioning the file that contains the suppressions like so:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq( "com.example" % "owasp-suppressions" % "1.1" )
lazy val dependencyCheckSettings = Seq(
  dependencyCheckSuppressionFiles := ?
)
```

How do I do this?